# is a static array a forward range?

Tags: d

This works:

```
int[] a = [ 1, 2, 3, 4 ];
fill(a, 5);
```

but this doesn't:

```
int[4] a = [ 1, 2, 3, 4 ];
fill(a, 5);
```

and I get this error:

> Error: template std.algorithm.fill(Range,Value) if (isForwardRange!(Range) && is(typeof(range.front = filler))) does not match any function template declaration

instead, I have to do this in order for it to work with static arrays:

```
int[4] a = [ 1, 2, 3, 4 ];
fill(a[], 5);
```

could any one explain this behavior please?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No. `isForwardRange` is `false` for static arrays, because they're not valid forward ranges. They must have a valid `front`, `empty`, and `popFront`.

A range must be mutated as it's iterated over. `popFront` removes the first element from the range, reducing the length of the range by one. static arrays cannot be mutated. Their *elements* can be, but they can't be.

```
int[5] a;
a.length = 4;
```

is illegal. So, `popFront` cannot work with static arrays and therefore static arrays cannot be ranges.

`front`, `empty`, and `popFront` are declared for arrays in std.array, and `front` and `empty` will work with static arrays, because they explicitly take dynamic arrays (not ranges), and static arrays can be implicitly converted to dynamic arrays when a function takes a dynamic array (a slice of the static array is taken). However, `popFront` won't work, because it requires a `ref` of a dynamic array. And as, I pointed out, `popFront` can't be made to work with static arrays regardless of `popFront`'s implementation, because you can't mutate a static array as would be required for a range.

Now as for `fill`, it takes a forward range, not an array. So, IFTI (implicit function template instantiation) will try and use the static array type (not the dynamic array type) with it. And since `isForwardRange` is `false` for a static array, `fill` fails to compile with a static array. However, when you slice the static array, you're then passing a dynamic array, for which `isForwardRange` *is* `true`. So, it works. And because, the slice points to the same elements, and `fill` mutates the elements and not the array, the elements in the static array are mutated by `fill`.

Be wary, however, of passing slices of static arrays to functions. As long as the static array exists, it's fine. But once the static array leaves scope, any slice of it is then invalid. So, doing something like

```
int[] foo()
{
    int[5] a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
    return find(a[], 3);
}
```

would be very bad. A reference to `a` is escaping `foo` - namely a slice of its last 3 elements.

So, if you are passing a slice of a static array to a function, you need to be sure that no references to that array escape. `fill`, however, should be fine.

Comment: Am I right in saying you have to slice with `Array` and `SList` as well? Seems like a bit of a design flaw.

Comment: It's not really a design flaw IMHO. It's more of a case that dynamic arrays are a weird special case of ranges. But since they're currently the most common case, it's what we're used to.A container would have to implicitly convert to its slice type for IFTI in order for it not need to be explicitly sliced when passing to a function, and that would make it much more difficult to pass containers to templated functions. And I'm not sure that it would be a good idea for all sliceable types to be automatically sliced with IFTI in general - even when just dealing with ranges.

Comment: You can think of it like this. Containers - including static arrays - need to be sliced in order to get a range over them. So, if you want a range over them for any reason - including passing to a range-based function - you have to explicitly slice them. But dynamic arrays are _already_ ranges rather than containers, so slicing isn't necessary.

Comment: Then why does `fill` require a range, why does it not require a general container / array which is slicable? Internally it could slice and obtain the range it so requires. Errors like this will then not occur.

Comment: @Daevius And why should `fill` be restricted to working on ranges gotten directly from containers? What if I want to only fill part of a range,  rather than an entire container? And since dynamic arrays aren't really containers (they don't own their memory) but are ranges, they wouldn't work with `fill` if it didn't operate on ranges. In general, the functions in Phobos operate on ranges, not containers. This is _far_ more flexible, especially since then you can effectively pipe range-based functions. The only "error" here is the fact that slicing a static array risks escaping references.

Comment: Think of how in C++'s STL, functions take iterators, not containers. That approach is _far_ more powerful. Phobos is doing the same thing, except with ranges, which are both safer (since you don't have to worry about stuff like passing the two iterators out of order) and even more powerful. You're not ever going to see much in the way of functions in Phobos which operate on containers any more than you'll see much in the STL operating on containers and for pretty much the same reasons.

Comment: Yes you are completely right. I overseen that. What about static array is implicitly convertible to range, and container has `alias this` with its internal range? I just find it strange that you need to (redundantly) slice your array. I guess you could see `a` as the array object and `a[]` as all its values (subtle difference). Where dyn. arrays are equal in both. `fill` only works on a multiple of values, whatever the array object is...

Comment: @Daevius There's nothing redundant about it. A dynamic array is a range. A static array is not. Also, a dynamic arrange _is_ a slice, whereas a static array is not. A static array owns its memory. A dynamic array does not. You're explicitly requesting that the static array be sliced so that you can get a dynamic array. You're getting a slice of it just like you'd get a slice of a container. If IFTI treated static arrays as dynamic arrays, then it would be harder to pass static arrays to templated functions as static arrays when you actually want a static array.

Answer (score 7):

`isForwardRange` checks for the existence of the `front`, `empty` properties and `popfront()` function

the issue is that `popfront()` would need to shrink the array, as you (should) know you can't resize a static array but a slice of a static array (essentially a normal dynamic array) can be resized (this of course doesn't affect the static array)

to clarify `a.popfront()` would need to transform a from `int[4]` to `int[3]` but that's not possible

Comment: i.e. The argument and return types of popfront must be the same?

Comment: `popfront` is a function that changes the `this` parameter so the `front` property changes (pointing to the 'next' element) (and maybe the `empty` property) this isn't possible with the static array because the length is set at compile time and part of the type.