# d2: assigning ranges/iterators to array slices

Tags: iterator, d, range

Consider following code:

```
enum size = 16;
double[size] arr1 = [...];
double[size] arr2 = [...];
process = (double x) { return (x + 1); };

arr2[] = map!(process)(arr1[]); // here
```

I have trouble converting results of `map` back to my plain array. Problem applies not only to `map`, but also to `take`, `repeat` and all those fine tools from `std.algorithm` and `std.range` that operate on ranges.

On this assignment, I get `Error: cannot implicitly convert expression (map(arr1[])) of type Result to double[]`. How can I evaluate range to array without using

```
uint i = 0;
foreach (x; map!(process)(arr1[])) {
    arr2[i] = x;
    i++;
}
```

?

Additionally, can someone please explain, why I must call `map!(process)(arr1[])` instead of `map!(process)(arr1)` with static arrays? Shouldn't static arrays be compatible with dynamic for means of iteration, or I don't get something?

Also, it seems that straightforward enumeration syntax `foreach (index, item; sequence)` does not work for ranges - are there workarounds? I guess the reason is the same as why ranges cannot be assigned to array slices.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Functions such as `map` and `filter` return ranges, not arrays, so simply assigning to an array isn't going to work any more than assigning a `string` to `wstring` is going to work. They're different types. And for many range-based functions (including `map` and `filter`), the ranges they return are actually lazy in order to avoid unnecessary computation, which makes them that much less compatible with an array. The solution is to use [`std.array.array`](http://dlang.org/phobos/std_array.html#array), which takes a range and creates a dynamic array from it. So, you could do

```
auto arr = array(map!process(origArray));
```

However, I would advise not converting a range into an array before you actually need to, since it can result in unnecessary computations, and it means allocating a new array. If you actually need an array, then by all means, use std.array.array to convert the range, but operating on the range can often be more efficient if you don't need an actual array. However, if you want to convert the result to a *static* array as opposed to a dynamic one, you're probably better off just assigning each element in a loop (and maybe skipping `map` altogether), since using std.array.array will then have allocated a dynamic array that you won't be using once you've assigned to the static array. It's a waste of memory.

Also, be aware that using static arrays with range-based functions can be risky in that they must slice the static array to get a dynamic array for the range-based functions to process, and if that dynamic array escapes the scope that the static array was declared in, then you're leaking references to data which no longer exists. For example,

```
auto func()
{
    int[5] arr;
    return map!process(arr[]);
}
```

would be very bad. However, as long as you're done using the slice and nothing refers to it  anymore (including any ranges that might have been created) before you exit the scope with the static array in it, you should be fine. It *is* something to be careful of though.

As for the question about having to slice static arrays, you really should ask that as a separate question, but two existing questions that relate to it are [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9575582/template-argument-inference-in-d) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8873265/is-a-static-array-a-forward-range). What it pretty much comes down to is that IFTI (Implicit Function Template Instantiation) instantiates using the exact type that it's given, and a static array is neither a dynamic array nor a range, so any templated function which specifically requires a dynamic array or a range will fail to compile with a static array. The compiler *will* implicitly slice static arrays to convert them to dynamic arrays for functions which explicitly take dynamic arrays, but those sort of implicit conversions don't happen with template instantiation, so you must explicitly slice static arrays to pass them to range-based functions.

As for the question about using foreach with indices and ranges, again, you shouldn't be asking multiple questions in the same question. Please post separate questions for each question that you have. What it comes down to though is that

```
foreach(elem; range)
{
    //stuff
}
```

gets lowered to something close to

```
for(; !range.empty; range.popFront())
{
    auto elem = range.front;
    //stuff
}
```

And that doesn't involve indices at all. It *could* be change to create an index variable for you, but it doesn't always make sense for ranges to have their index iterating by one like that on every iteration (much as it usually would be fine), and so that hasn't been done. It's simple enough to add your own counter though.

```
{
    size_t i;
    foreach(elem; range)
    {
        //stuff
        ++i;
    }
}
```

`opApply` does support using indices with foreach, but it isn't a range, and doesn't work with range-based functions.

Comment: Thank you, Jonathan! I know that ranges and arrays are different types, but thought that D could implement some sort of implicit convertion, as ranges are convertible to arrays as long as they are finite and their elements are type compatible with array's ones. I'm aware of difference of stack and heap allocations, and computation and memory overhead of array-izing, but thanks for warning anyway :) Also, thanks for making it clear with IFTI - if I understood this right, in future this might change to allow implicit slicing static arrays, but now we should use this way due to imperfection.

Comment: IFTI _might_ be changed to implicitly convert static arrays to dynamic ones, but I doubt it. It still needs to be possible to have templated functions take static arrays (so always converting them for template instantiation would be bad), and IFTI doesn't keep trying until it finds an implicit conversion which works (that would be expensive and would change the semantics of a number of templates). So, I'd expect that you'll always have to slice static arrays to pass them to range-based functions, but an improvement may be made at some point to at least reduce the problem.

Comment: I would recommend using `staticArray` instead of `array` where possible because it doesn't allocate GC memory. The efficient way of programming would be to set up a stack-allocated array where possible (this is the case for mere processing tasks) and assign all elements of the range to the array. I don't know myself how to do that in D but I'd like to know it. Also it would be nice, if such a range would behave just like an iterator with an array as background storage, so that you just could retrieve the array from the range back without any performance overhead.